# create new columns result in NaN

Tags: python, pandas

[after merging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZMa0.png)I tried to create a new column with 3 columns in a csv file.But if one of the column value is NaN ,the entire value updated to NaN instead of skipping it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\RAHNA KM\Downloads\Accident_death.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
df['Address']= df["ResidenceCity"].astype(str) +" "+ df["ResidenceCounty"].astype(str) +" "+ df["ResidenceState"]
df.head()
```

Comment: provide sample data

Comment: where is your merging? the only thing i see is that you are creating a new column with a adress

Comment: [link](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/accidental-drug-related-deaths-january-2012-sept-2015)

Comment: i tried to combine the columns into a new column address

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it is doing that, but filling the 'NaN's with something this else get you around it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv(r'TestData.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
df2 = df.fillna('Unknown')
df2['Address']= df2["ResidenceCity"].astype(str) +" "+ df2["ResidenceCounty"].astype(str) +" "+ df2["ResidenceState"]
df2.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, you can combine multiple columns and drop or ignore the NAN values.

```
df['NewColumn']=pd.concat([df['Column1'].dropna(),df['Column2'].dropna(),df['Column3'].dropna()])
```

Comment: this is not working.I sorted one problem but still NaN values are adding.

Answer (score 0):

The phenomenon you find is based on this basic principle “np.nan is actually a float type”，read [Missing data handling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html#missing-data-handling)may help you.
Example：

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[[np.nan, 'BBB', np.nan],
 ['AAA', np.nan, 'CCC'],
 [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
 [np.nan, 'BBB', 'CCC']],
columns=list('ABC'))

# fill NaN with ''
df = df.fillna('')

df['new_col'] = df['A']+df['B']+df['C']
```